# How to remove access denied error while copying data from S3 bucket(with kms key) into Redshift. (S3 bucket is in cross account)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I have two accounts: `Account A` and `Account B`.

I'm trying to load data from cross-account S3 bucket (Account B) to Redshift tables (which is in Account A).

```sql
copy employee 
from 's3://test-data/sampledata1.csv' 
region 'eu-west-1'
iam_role 'arn:aws:iam::446633115643:role/redshift-test'
delimiter ',';
```

The Redshift cluster that I launched in Account A has a separate VPC, no public access.

The S3 bucket where I kept my data is encrypted with a KMS key.

I changed bucket policy too with:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "DelegateS3Access",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::446633115643:root"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:Get*",
                "s3:List*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::test-data",
                "arn:aws:s3:::test-data/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The output of this case should be: The data must be loaded to Redshift tables. But I am facing this error:

> Invalid operation: S3ServiceException:Access Denied,Status 403,Error AccessDenied

Comment: Is that Bucket Policy on the bucket in Account B? In the Bucket Policy, can you try changing the principal to the ARN of the IAM Role used in the copy command (`arn:aws:iam::446633115643:role/redshift-test`)? If that doesn't work, it might be related to the fact that the data is encrypted and the IAM Role is not permitted to access the KMS Key to decrypt it. See: [Troubleshoot Access Denied Errors for Cross-Account Users in S3](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cross-account-access-denied-error-s3/)

Comment: Yes that policy is on the Bucket. The Iam role I mentioned has s3 readonly access too.  Can u plz tell how to permit IAM role to access KMS key to decrypt it?

Comment: and I changed principal arn to this arn:aws:iam::446633115643:root . But didn't help

Comment: Did you follow the above link regarding KMS permissions?

Comment: Yes, followed this link too : https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cross-account-access-denied-error-s3/ . Still getting same error

Comment: Is Enhanced VPC Routing enabled for Redshift? Is there an existing VPC Endpoint for S3 that has an endpoint policy that restricts S3 access? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/enhanced-vpc-working-with-endpoints.html

Comment: Thanks the issue got resolved. Made changes in assume roles